# What distribution $\frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^{d}X_i $ will follow if $X_i$ is a bernoulli random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am a newbie on probability and statistics.

On the course of studying binomial distribution, I was curious about the distribution of  'sample mean' of binomial distribution.

---

Formally, the question was followed.

Let $ X_i\;\; \text{~}\;\; Bernoulli\;(p) $ , and then $ \sum_{i=1}^{d}x_i \;\; \text{~} \;\; Binomial\;(d,p)  $

Then what distribution $ \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^{d}X_i   $ will follow? Plot it for p = 0.6, d= 11

---

I don't ask you to solve this problem. What I want to know is that is there any explicit PDF form that such random variable follows.

To my knowledge, as $\sum_{i=1}^{d} X_i $ is a discrete random variable, a linear transformation, $ \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^{d} X_i  $ also follows the binomial distribution, say for $ Z =   \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^{d} X_i $,    the pdf of $Z$ will be   $$ P(Z = z) =  \dbinom{1}{z}p^{z} (1-p)^{1-z}  \;    $$

Am I right? Could you give any guide that what distribution the random variable $Z$ will follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider we know $P(X=x)$. What will be $P(\frac{X}{d}=z)$? By setting $z=\frac{x}{d}$, the answer is clear.

Specifically for your example: The distribution is defined for $z=0,\frac{1}{d},\frac{2}{d},\dots,1$. As you correctly mention, the sum is Binnomial and multiplication by a constant is a linear transformation. The distribution uses practically the probability mass from the original Binomial, i.e you have to multiply $z$ by $d$ so you obtain the right value
$$ P(Z=z) = \dbinom{d}{zd}p^{zd}(1-p)^{d-zd}
$$